# Blank map with Google Map V2 and SupportMapFragment (and no, this is not an API key issue)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I know there are many post like this, but most of them are related to a wrong API key but this is not my case.

I know that the API key is OK, as if i change it i will get an authorization error. And from the API console, if i go to "Reports" i can see all my request.

I followed the official tutorial, i read it 10 times :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Something strange to be noticed:

When the fragment is display for the first time, the grid is blank. But if i turn off the screen, then turn it on (onResum) the map appears but it stuck, i can't move the map or use zoom controller)
And, if from my fragment, i center the map on a location, the map is centered. So forget about API key stuff.

Here is my manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.restoaparis"
       android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
       <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

       <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >


      <activity android:name=".StartActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/FapiaoTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
       >     
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
       android:value="MY_KEY"/>


</application>
```

Here is my layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Here is my fragment (as you can see i use Sherlock)

```
    public class FragmentContact extends SherlockFragment
    {

      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }

      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan2 , container, false);

            return view;    
     }

     }
```

Of course, i got no error, no warning, from logcat.

I just got some debug message about memory , i don't think it has anything to do whith my problem.

/dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x559da000 size:9539584 offset:7798784 fd:115

I add google-play-service as library of my eclipse project

Any idea ? please help me

i m nice guy, i deserve it

Comment: The layout which contains the <fragment/> is plan2?

Comment: Try downloading and running a complete, known-to-be-working Maps V2 app, like one of mine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Basic. All you should need to do with that project is supply your API key and point the project at your copy of ActionBarSherlock. If my app works and yours does not, then you can start experimenting to see what I am doing that is different than what you are doing.

Comment: Try clearing the cache for Google Play Services - From main phone menu, this is usually under `Menu->Settings->Application Manager->Google Play Services`, then tap `Clear cache`.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced similar problem and I solved my issue by adding onResume().
In my case I used MapView class.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Happened when A ViewPager in another nested fragment. In my case, this is what I needed as I am using the SupportMapFragment:

((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_activity)).onResume();

Answer (score 0):

You short of another meta-data element :)

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also one more thing.  You are using SupportMapFragment which is to be used for API 11 and below.  Since you have a minimumSDKversion of 11 and most of the phones these days are above API 11, you might want to consider converting this to MapFragment.

Answer (score -1):

Do not put a fragment inside fragment via xml. [This is not supported](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).